# Enumerate with item name breaking margin

Tags: margins, enumerate, lncs

I'm using LNCS style in my document. When I do `enumerate` with item names, the names seems to get out of the margins:

[image]

Currently I use `Geometry` for the margins:

```
\usepackage[top=1in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

And the enumeration:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\begin{enumerate}
\item[\underline{Substructure 1}:]Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\item[\underline{Substructure 2}:]Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{enumerate}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is with the `enumitem` package, using the `[align=left]` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
\item[Long Test 1:] \lipsum[1]
\item[Long Test 2:] \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with an appropriate `leftmargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
versions of Lorem Ipsum.

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=7.5em]
  \item[\underline{Substructure 1}:]
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
  specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
  into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
  versions of Lorem Ipsum.

  \item[\underline{Substructure 2}:]
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
  specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap 
  into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised 
  in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including 
  versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```